# Unity Cardboard on Nexus 6 bug: U.I of previous scene is remained on view when new Cardboard scene is loaded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I develop VR app by using Unity and Cardboard SDK.

My first scene is a non-Cardboard-VR scene contains U.I dropdown list and confirm button.

When I execute loadLevel() to the Cardboard VR scene, **my previous U.I will still be remained on the view, in corrupted form**, behind the rectangular VR cameras, like this one:

[image]

[image]

This bug is only happen on **Nexus 6**. I built my this VR app on Moto G, Samsung Note 2, Note 3, Nexus 4, Nexus 5 and Nexus 6.

Seems like it is a Cardboard rendering bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the bug myself.

This issue was solved by updating my

**Unity 5 Pro to v5.1.0f3**    and

**Cardboard SDK for Unity v0.5**.